# Filtering records in one dataframe based on matching values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'Emma'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18], 'Sex':['M','M','M','F'} 
# Create DataFrame 
df_all = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

And another dataframe, for example:

```
queries= {'Name':['Tom', 'nick']}
df_some = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I need a new dataframe that will contain only the records of df_all where the "Name" column in "df_some" matches with "Name" column in "df_all".

For example, the resulting data frame should only have two rows (Tom and nick). For example:

```
Tom  20 M
nick 21 M
```

Comment: Use `df = df_some.merge(df)`

Comment: Or `df_all.loc[df_all["Name"].isin(df_some["Name"])]`.